# Question about position of "habe" in "Perfekt" tense

Tags: perfect-tense

I was told that this sentence is correct:

> „Heute habe ich jemanden getroffen, aber wie ich oben gesagt habe…“

My question is: why cannot I write the last part in the same way as in the first part? Like this:

> „Heute habe ich jemanden getroffen, aber wie habe ich oben gesagt…“

Any reference will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, *wie* is a conjunction introducing a subordinate clause. In subordinate clauses introduced by a conjunction, verb-last order applies. Because of this, your second example is incorrect.

Comment: what are other conjunctions apart from "wie" that I should consider?